# Return just an object within array from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a db like this

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "Shirley",
            "kind": "Bugatti"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jessica",
            "kind": "Maserati"
        },      
    ]
}
```

I have a query like this

```
db.people.findOne({"name: "Tom"});
```

I just want to return the object where `"name": "Jessica"`

```
{
    "name": "Jessica",
    "kind": "Maserati"
}
```

How can I do this?

I tried

```
db.people.findOne({"name": "Tom"}, {"cars.name": 1});
db.people.findOne({"name": "Tom"}, {"cars.name.Jessica": 1});
```

I'm trying to prevent returning the whole thing then sorting everything after.

Comment: Which object are you trying to get to?  The second one?  The last one?  First one alphabetically by name?  The "Jessica" object meets several criteria and you didn't spell out what criteria you are searching for.

Comment: Just trying to pluck one object via "name".

Comment: The first object in the query is your filter and the second object is the list of fields to return.  You are mixing them.

Comment: No I'm not. they query is adequate. I'm trying to trim down the fields so that I just return that one object. Attaching a more specific query is still going to give me the whole doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.people.findOne({"name": "Tom"}, {"cars": { $elemMatch : { "name": "Jessica"}}});

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526453188257d12214ea287d"),
    "cars" : [
        {
            "name" : "Jessica",
            "kind" : "Maserati"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thought you just wanted to project `name:'jessica'`?

Comment: Why would I want what I queried for? I said what I wanted to return in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is as good as you'll get without using the aggregation framework.